# Conditions for inequality

Tags: inequality

I just found out while doing my ANCOVA assignment that the inequality

$$\sum_{i=1}^{15}x_i \sum_{i=1}^{15} y_i\leq 3\times\left(\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i \sum_{i=1}^5 y_i+\sum_{i=6}^{10} x_i \sum_{i=6}^{10} y_i+\sum_{i=11}^{15} x_i \sum_{i=11}^{15} y_i\right)$$

does not always hold. A counter-example is the pair of vectors $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{15})=(18.3,20.4,22.1,20.8,20.8,23.5,17.2,18.3,21,24.2,26.5,18.3,18.9,18.9,21)$ and $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_{15})=(47.6,60,60.7,65.1,67.9,69.8,44.3,47.2,58.5,70.9,76.1,49.6,50.3,51.8,58.9)$ where the LHS of the inequality is equal to $272572.74$ and the RHS is equal to $272538.54$.

What condition(s) will ensure that the inequality will hold?

Comment: For a sufficient condition, ordering the $x_i, y_i$ in the same manner should work - you will need to check, this is just a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With
$$
a_1 := \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i \, , \quad
a_2 := \sum_{i=6}^{10} x_i \, ,\quad
a_3 := \sum_{i=11}^{15} x_i \\
b_1 := \sum_{i=1}^5 y_i \, ,\quad
b_2 :=  \sum_{i=6}^{10}y_i \, ,\quad
b_3 := \sum_{i=11}^{15} y_i
$$
the inequality becomes
$$
(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)(b_1 + b_2 + b_3) \le 3(a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3)
$$
and that is equivalent to
$$
(a_1 - a_2)(b_1 - b_2) + (a_1 - a_3)(b_1 - b_3) + (a_2 - a_3)(b_2 - b_3) \ge 0 \, .
$$
This is for example satisfied if the differences
$a_1-a_2, a_2 - a_3, a_3 - a_1$ have the same signs as
the differences $b_1 - b_2, b_2 - b_3, b_3 - b_1$,
and in particular if  $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3$
are both ordered in increasing order or both ordered in decreasing
order.

Comment: Thank you Martin. The value of your answer is actually in reminding me that simplifying notations can sometimes clarify concepts involved. Much appreciated.